# What is Auto Aperture Mode on Nikon Speedlight?

Tags: nikon, flash

I am not familiar with the "Auto Aperture" mode in Nikon Speedlights.  I've been using a non-Nikon flash and I have not tried AA mode before.  What is it exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, Auto Aperture and Auto Flash mode use flash based measuring of the scene. If possible the flash can use aperture and sensitivity data from the Camera (Auto Aperture) or you have to set the values manually (Auto Flash). You can use both modes for Aperture Priority mode on camera.

Per default, the Nikon Flashes (SB-800, SB-900, SB-910) do use a pre-flash to more accurately control the flash output - but the pre-flash can be deactivated on SB-900 and SB-910 via custom functions and on SB-800 with some kind of trick.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using exposure information gathered via the lens (TTL), Auto and Auto Aperture modes use a sensor built into the flash unit itself to measure the reflected light from a scene and adjust flash output.

The Auto modes have the advantage of avoiding the slight shutter delay introduced by TTL modes, and also avoid the pre-flash which can make pets or children flinch and blink, thus ruining potentially good shots.